# How do I change the Function Declaration Color in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the Function Declaration Color in VSCode?
The only setting I've found is

"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
"functions": "#FF0000"
}

Which changes Declarations and calls.  I just want to change Declarations.

Thanks